# Pass context variables from two view functions to the same template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I trying to render values from two function to one html and I not sure how to perform this task.
I suppose to use "return render" in both function? and how should be in urls.py to read this both functions?
For now I have as is bellow and of course TopAlerts not returning anything. Any suggestions?

views.py

```
def OneWeekRequest(request):
    #code here....
    ......
    return render_to_response('weeklyreport.html',
                              {'n1week': n1week,
                               'g1week': g1week,
                               'fweeks': fweeks,
                               'g4weeks': g4weeks,
                               'form': form,
                               'start': start,
                               'end': end,
                               'wnumber': wnumber,
                               'speriod': selectedrange},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def TopAlerts(request):
    #code here....
        ......    
    return render(request, 'weeklyreport.html', {'tops': tops})
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'platforms.views.queryset'),
    url(r'^weeklyreport/$', 'weeklyreport.views.OneWeekRequest'),
    #url(r'^weeklyreport/', include('weeklyreport.urls')),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return two views from one URL. A URL always points to one single view (although of course multiple URLs can point to the same view).

It sounds like your `TopAlerts` view should really be an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags-inclusion-tags).

Answer (score 1):

I created templatetag.py in templatetags

```
from django import template
from platforms.models import Platform, Event

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def top_alerts(top):
    tops = Event.objects.filter(sourcetype_id__in=[1, 3],
                                  status_id__in=[1,2,7,8],
                                  event_datetime__range=('2014-04-07', '2014-04-13')
                                  ).exclude(service_id__in=[759, 7]
                                            ).values("event_datetime",
                                                     "platform__name",
                                                     "host__name","service__name",
                                                     "eventtype__name",
                                                     "status__name", "data")
    return {'tops': tops}
```

and in my template.

```
{% load templatetag %}
and
{% top_alerts top %}
```

And is working fine, but i not entirely sure if this goes correct way with my project.